# always_use_default_target_path doesn't work when set on false

Tags: php, symfony, security, fosuserbundle

I have installed `fos user bundle` in Symfony 2.7.

Everything works fine but I have problem with redirecting. It allways redirect me to home: `localhost/xxx/app_dev.php/`. My security.yml

```
#security.yml


security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle

                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                always_use_default_target_path: false
                default_target_path:            /
                target_path_parameter:          _target_path
                use_referer:                    false

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

What problem can live?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your login form, what input fields is it contain?

In the configuration you added:

```
            target_path_parameter:          _target_path
```

This will use the _target_path hidden input field in your login form to determine where to redirect the user after login. (I suppose this is an empty string or defaults to the /)

Uncomment this line and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Regards to Andras Laczi answer I added made my own flexible solution (probably better one exist)

Step ONE: I added to security.yml following line:

```
firewalls:
    main:
         form_login:
            ...               
            failure_path_parameter: _failure_path
```

Step TWO: In twig, in places where I want to generate redirecting to login i added

```
  <a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_login')}}?targetPath={{ app.request.attributes.get('_route') }}">Log in</a>
```

Step THREE: Overriding FOSUserBundle SecurityController, and adding following lines somewhere in LoginAction

```
$targetPath = $request->query->get('targetPath', 'app_index');
$failurePath = $targetPath;
```

Step FOUR: Overriding FOSUserBundle Login Form adding following hidden fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ targetPath }}" />  
<input type="hidden" name="_failure_path" value="/login?targetPath={{ failurePath }}" />
```